# C Programming The program result is changed by time(&start) function of <time.h>

Tags: c, time, time-t, time.h

Recently I experienced very strange situation by my C program.
Usually my program works fine, but if I add just a few lines to check elapsed time, the result changes.

The code of which result changed is:

```
while (!feof(pfInputFile) && (c = fgetc(pfInputFile)) != EOF){
    for(i = 1 ; i < SEED_SIZE ; i++){
    pcSeq[i-1] = pcSeq[i];  // Shift left all sequence
    }
    pcSeq[SEED_SIZE - 1] = c;
}
```

And the code I added and cause a problem is below:

```
#include <time.h>

time_t start, end;
time(&start); time(&end);
```

And then, the characters that are read by the above source code are changed to unrecognized character.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger (like `gdb` on Linux); you should compile with warnings and debug info enabled (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux); and you should post all your code (the bug is probably elsewhere) if you want us to help.

Comment: if nothing else the `feof` call is pointless; only check the `((c=getchar())==EOF)`

Comment: Since you don't show the complete minimal code which reproduces the problem, there is nothing we can do except guess.  In particular, you don't show how `pcSeq` is defined, or how it is initialized.  You might well find that calling `printf("Hello World\n");` instead of `time()` also changes the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough details but I'll take a wild guess.

You returned a pointer to a local variable `pcSeq`. Then in another function you call `time(&start)` with the result that the `start` variable now shares the same stack address that `pcSeq` had, so it got overwritten.